# this.props.media is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue with my React App, when I attempt to add the react-responsive-decorator library I am getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: this.props.media is not a function

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import Responsive from 'react-responsive-decorator';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import Header from '../Includes/header';

// Import stylesheets
import '../../css/global.css';
import '../../css/parallax.css';
import '../../css/home.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
      isMobile: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.props.media({ minWidth: 768 }, () => {
        this.setState({
          isMobile: false
        });
    });

      this.props.media({ maxWidth: 768 }, () => {
        this.setState({
          isMobile: true
        });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { isMobile } = this.state;
    const { className, ...props } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classnames('App', className)} {...props}>
      <div>
        {isMobile ?
          <div>Mobile</div> :
          <div>Not mobile</div>
        }
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is very clear. `Media` isn't a function. Debug it and see what type it is.

Comment: I've followed the instructions from the documentation here -https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decorate your component with the `@Responsive` annotation to be able to use `this.props.media`.

```
@Responsive
class App extends Component {
  // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to **Kaivosukeltaja**'s solution above is to return a wrapped, Higher Order component, export like so:

```
// ...
import Responsive from 'react-responsive-decorator';

class App extends React.Component {

    // ...

}
```

export default **Responsive**(App);

Live running example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zl3w9mmj53